# If all replicas will sync up eventually, what's the point of read repairs?

Tags: cassandra

If all replicas will sync up eventually, what's the point of read repairs?

Wouldn't you have cases where if you have a write that's being sent to all replicas, then a read repair happens before the write, wouldn't you essentially be duplicating that same write twice?

Comment: what do you mean by "write that's being sent to all replicas"? is this referring to a write with consistency level ALL?

Comment: no, I'm talking about just writes being sent to all replicas in general. im under the impression that the consistency level simply refers to the number of acknowledgements one needs for the write to be deemed successful. The data is still going to be replicated to all replicas. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: you're absolutely right. see the doc - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html

I'm also wondering what the point of read-repair is, given that all replicas would be updated eventually. perhaps it speeds up the process?  the 'accepted answer' does not really answer the question, and is rather unclear.

Comment: his answer seems to answer it pretty well for me. what exactly do you think is wrong with his answer?

Comment: jason-mantra - I've read it ~10 or so times and I still think it could have been written with more clarity. Compare my answer with the first paragraph of the accepted answer (they convey the same meaning).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres a few things, blocking read repairs, async read repairs, and if either are needed.

Blocking read repairs: Quorum reads are monotonically consistent for awhile now. If you read it twice you should get the same answer. People tend to use QUORUM reads as wanting stronger consistency, so the blocking read repairs prevent reads from going back in time. If this behavior ends it would cause potential surprises to existing applications. However the latency impact of these repairs have been causing issues and it may still be changed in very near future. You cannot currently disable this behavior and it will always be on.

Async read repairs: Repairs in background can be disabled or happen only a small percentage of time, or (recommended) only within a DC. This reduces background impact as there isnt as much cross DC traffic. This is controlled by the dc_local and global read repair chance settings. When you do a ONE or LOCAL_ONE etc query it will depending on that chance wait for the rest of the responses and compare results for a read repair.

Statistically your far more likely to be having unnecessary work with *async* read repairs as on a normal functioning perfect system they are not needed. Hinted Handoff however is not perfect and there are cases where hints are lost. In these situations the consistency will not be met until a anti-entropy repair is run (should be weekly or even daily depending on how repairs run, inc or full etc).

So other than for the sake of monotonic consistency (blocking on QUORUM+ requests), read repairs are *not* really critical or needed. Its something people have used to statistically put cluster in a more consistent state faster (maybe). Lots of people run without async read repairs (you cannot currently disable the read repair mechanism fwiw), and theres even [serious talk of removing options around it completely](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13910) due to misunderstandings.

Comment: @FuzzyAmi  "The read repairs provides some statistical likelihood of becoming consistent much earlier in these bad corner cases." which to me he's basically saying that in some scenarios it might actually fix a consistency issue. As mentioned, anti-entropy repairs is still necessary because this "fix" would be reliant on you doing a quorum read so if you're constantly reading from one replica, there may have been a problem somewhere that that replica you're reading from actually didn't get the updated data (past hinted handoff time, node went offline came back online for example).

Comment: @FuzzyAmi from what I'm getting is that if your application is reliant on eventual consistency in that R + W < N, then it can be a problem. Under normal circumstances where there's no malfunction read repairs as you mentioned will speed up the process but not really necessary it seems.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario that makes sense to me is this:

1. You write the data to a node (or a subset of the cluster)
2. You read the data (with Quorum), and one of the nodes has the fresher data.

because you specified `QUROUM`, several nodes are being asked for the value before the response is sent to the client. But because the data is fresher on *one* of the nodes, a blocking read-repair must first happen, to update all of them.

in this case, the read-repair needs to happen because the "eventual update" has yet to happen.

Comment: check out my other comments see if any of it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

In highly dynamic applications with many nodes, there are times when an eventually consistent write doesn't make it to the node PRIOR to a read request for that piece of data on that node.  This is common in environments with heavy load on an undersized cluster, unknown hardware issues and other reasons.  Its likely also where write consistency is set to one, while read consistency is set to local_quorum.

Example 1: random & sporadic network drops due to an unknown network switch failing that affects the write to the node but doesn't affect the read.

Example 2: the write occurs during a peak load time period, and as a result doesn't make it to the overloaded node, prior to the read request.